# How to render Div Content based on value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, conditional-rendering

I have a scenario where the contents of the `div` are to be displayed as per the value returned from the java-script function

pseudo HTML:

```
<div>
if(true==myfunction())
{
<p>True is returned from the javascript function</p>
}
else
{
<p>False is returned from the javascript function</p>
}
</div>
```

pseudo javascript function

```
myFunction()
{
var x = false;

// Some code to decide value of x.

return x;
}
```

I am using Asp.net core, my Javacript code is present in site.js and html code is present in cshtml.

It would be very helpful is someone can suggest an approach on how to achieve this.
Note: The code presented is not the actual code, but represents the actual scenario.

Comment: Are you using razor views?

Answer (score 0):

This can be one approach

```js
const par = document.createElement('p');
par.innerHTML = `${x ? 'True' : 'False'} is rendered from javascript function`;

document.getElementById('idx').appendChild(par);
```

You need to give an id to your div tag
`html<div id="idx"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

So many different ways to do this. It will really depend on your code and when and how you are going to be setting the values.

The following simple example works from a button click. There is not enough information in your question to know if this is the best option for you.

Suggest updating your question with the real code so you can get an answer that is closer to what you really need. Please include any error messages you are getting too.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spn = document.getElementById("jsValue");
  var val = (this.value == "1") ? "True" : "False";
  spn.textContent = val;
}

window.onload = function() {
  var b = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  var i, max = b.length;
  for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
    b[i].addEventListener("click",myFunction,false);
  }
}
```

```html
<p><span id="jsValue">unknown</span> is returned from the javascript function</p>
<p><button value="1">Set true</button> <button value="0">Set false</button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new DOM Node and then append it to the body with condition or whatever.

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>
  function myFunction(x) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    if (x === true) {
      var node = document.createTextNode(
        "True is returned from the javascript function."
      );
      para.appendChild(node);
    } else {
      var node = document.createTextNode(
        "False is returned from the javascript function."
      );
      para.appendChild(node);
    }
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
  }

  myFunction(true);
</script>
```

more info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Comment: This is pretty much the solution I was looking for. Thanks a lot for prompt reply.

Comment: @RishabhNigam Glad I could help. You can choose this answer as accepted ;)